# Error con la funcion RETURN de PHP - Post [actualizado]

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo un problema con una funcion que estoy haciendo ya que solo me da el primar datos de la tabla y no una lista `NOTA:` si funcion con el `echo` pero sale en el top del sitio y lo que quiero es que funciona con `return` ya que estoy usando HOOKS para el sistema bueno espero que me puedan ayudar y Gracias

```
function system_contact() {

    global $con,$db,$error,$lang_text;
    $userID = userdata('userID',true);//User in session
//->
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".T_FRIENDS." WHERE user_one = '$userID' OR user_two = '$userID' ")or die(mysqli_error());
    $query = $sql;
    $num_rows  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($num_rows != 0 ){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $user_one = $row['user_one'];//user one

        if($user_one == $userID){

            $user_two = $row['user_two'];
            $friends = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".T_USERS." WHERE userID = '$user_two'")or die(mysqli_error());
            $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($friends);

            $result_list[] = $fila;

                foreach($result_list as $fila){
                    $ECHO_CODE = '
                    <div class="wall_chat_users">
                        <img id="image_user_chat" src="./assets/img/avatar_default.png"></img>
                        <p id="name_user_chat">'.$fila['user'].'<spam class="message_counter_user_spam">42</spam></p>
                    </div>
                    ';

                }
                return @$ECHO_CODE;         

            }else{

                $friends = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".T_USERS." WHERE userID = '$user_one'")or die(mysqli_error());
                $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($friends);



                $ECHO_CODE = '
                    <div class="wall_chat_users">
                        <img id="image_user_chat" src="./assets/img/avatar_default.png"></img>
                        <p id="name_user_chat">'.$fila['user'].'<spam class="message_counter_user_spam">42</spam></p>
                    </div>
                ';
                foreach($friends as $fila){

                }
                //return @$ECHO_CODE;   

            }
        }

    }else{            


        $ECHO_CODE = '

            <div id="user_no_contact">
                <img class="user_no_contact_img" src="{{CONFIG theme_url}}/img/no_contact.png"></img>
                <p class="user_no_contact_p" >{{ADD_TEXT You_have_no_contact}}</p>
            </div>  

                <!--You don\'t have friends-->
        ';

        return @$ECHO_CODE;

    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1- Los datos si estan en la base de datos.

2- En esta funcion recibo los datos de la funcion que esta arriba en la pregunta como lo hago estoy usando `HOOKS` para eso, para los que no saben que son los `HOOKS` es algo como un plugin asi como usa wordpress.

3- Con esta funcion busco el texto seleccionado que esta en la platilla y asi meto la funcion dentro del `DIV`.

4- Cuando uso la funcion `echo` si me da la lista con los datos pero me los da en el TOP y no dentro del `DIV` error.

5- si uso la funcion `return` si me da los datos dentro del DIV pero solo me da el primaro no una lista.

que puedo hacer con ello o donde esta el problema?

Comment: el problema cual es exactamente? podrias mostrar el problema? es que estas devolviendo una sola fila, puede ser?

Comment: Sí en la tabla user  tengo 3 datos pero solo me da el primaro y yo quiero una lista

Comment: por que en tu return haces @$ECHO_CODE de donde sacaste esa sintáxis?

Comment: para no tener notas de error en la linia

Comment: a ninguna de las variables ECHO_CODE le estas agregando el string mas el nuevo string, solo estas reemplazando lo que tienen

Comment: como no entiendo?

Comment: ¿El título no debería decir "return" en vez de "ruturn"?

Comment: si tienes razo se me fue la "U" lo siento

Comment: @AlfredoPaz es para ignorar los mensajes de error, se lo debe utilizar con cuidado. https://secure.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: gracias @KacosPro tanto tiempo usando PHP y no lo conocía

Comment: @AlfredoPaz el buen PHP, nunca dejará de sorpendernos :D

Answer (score 4):

mas alla del problema con tu $ECHO_CODE, nunca estas concatenando el string, por lo tanto, siempre devuelve lo ultimo que encuentra dentro de tu for each

tu codigo deberia ser:

```
$ECHO_CODE = ''
foreach($result_list as $fila){
    $ECHO_CODE .= '
    <div class="wall_chat_users">
    <img id="image_user_chat" src="./assets/img/avatar_default.png"></img>
    <p id="name_user_chat">'.$fila['user'].'<spam class="message_counter_user_spam">42</spam></p>
    </div>
    ';
}
```

Notese el `.` para concatenar el string varias veces contra la misma variable.

Comment: se lo que es concatenar pero no es eso aun tengo el error otra que tenga en mente

Answer (score 1):

¿Se soluciona con esto?

En la linea que se inserta el `array` has de establecerlo desde el inicio.

```
// Fijate en la Variable has de tener las claves
// de este tipo [] para que sea un array la variable


    $fila[] = mysqli_fetch_array($friends);
```

Comment: no funciona el array solo me da un dato

Comment: Una pregunta casó mirastes su código ya que esa función ya la está usando y no le funcionó

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así que habían varios fallos técnicos...

```html
$ECHO_CODE = '';
foreach($result_list as $fila){
    $ECHO_CODE . = '<div class="wall_chat_users"><img id="image_user_chat" src="./assets/img/avatar_default.png" /><p id="name_user_chat">'.$fila['user'] . '<spam class="message_counter_user_spam">42</spam></p></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
function system_contact() {

    global $con,$db,$error,$lang_text;
    $userID = userdata('userID',true);
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".T_FRIENDS." WHERE user_one = '$userID' OR user_two = '$userID' ")or die(mysqli_error());
    $query = $sql;
    $num_rows  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($num_rows != 0 ){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $user_one = $row['user_one'];//user one

        if($user_one == $userID){

            $user_two = $row['user_two'];
            $friends = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".T_USERS." WHERE userID = '$user_two'")or die(mysqli_error());
            $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($friends);

            $result_list[] = $fila;

                foreach($result_list as $fila){
                    $ECHO_CODE = '<div class="wall_chat_users"><img id="image_user_chat" src="./assets/img/avatar_default.png" /><p id="name_user_chat">' . $fila['user'] . '<spam  class="message_counter_user_spam">42</spam></p></div>';
                }
                return @$ECHO_CODE;         
            }else{
                $friends = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".T_USERS." WHERE userID = '$user_one'")or die(mysqli_error());
                $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($friends);



                $ECHO_CODE = '<div class="wall_chat_users"><img id="image_user_chat" src="./assets/img/avatar_default.png" /> <p id="name_user_chat">' . $fila['user'] . '<spam class="message_counter_user_spam">42</spam></p></div>';
                foreach($friends as $fila){

                }
                //return @$ECHO_CODE;   

            }
        }

    }else{            


        $ECHO_CODE = '<div id="user_no_contact"><img  class="user_no_contact_img" src="{{CONFIG theme_url}}/img/no_contact.png" /> <p class="user_no_contact_p" >{{ADD_TEXT You_have_no_contact}}</p></div>';

        return @$ECHO_CODE;

    }
}
```

Comment: He visto varios errores de escritura ahora si pruebas con este código que he revisado aquí te debería de funcionar

Comment: Hola. Dejar muchas respuestas a una pregunta no es algo correcto. La respuesta tiene que ser en lo posible unica. Si no soluciona el problema editala hasta q lo solucione.

Comment: @PolFlórezViciana no todo esta igual miren mejor les hago un mapa del sistema para que tengan una idea de como esta si

Comment: @gbianchi no todo esta igual miren mejor les hago un mapa del sistema para que tengan una idea de como esta si